# New to Python: Interactive Broker API function

Tags: python

I came across this code in python:
https://github.com/blampe/IbPy/blob/master/demo/example_opt

When I walk through the debugger and debugger is at location:

```
con.reqAccountUpdates(1, '')
```

The console automatically prints the account details. How do I instead dump those details in a variable or in a file instead.

Answer (score 1):

you need to define an accountInfoHandler first:

```
def accountInfoHandler(msg):
    global preMargin
    if msg.key=='InitMarginReq':
        preMargin=msg.value
```

then you initialize the variable and register this handler on Connection

```
preMargin=-1
con=ibConnection()
con.register(accountInfoHandler,message.updateAccountValue)
```

last,you call

```
con.reqAccountUpdates(1, '')
sleep(1)
```

the variable preMargin will be assigned.

for a set of account variables you can extract, pls refer to this link:
https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/software/api/apiguide/java/updateaccountvalue.htm